# how to store java loop output?

Tags: java, for-loop

here this is  my random mail generator code, I would like to save that random mails,  how can I do that?

```
public class stupit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println("username"+randomInt+"@gmail.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
 username394@gmail.com
 username429@gmail.com
 username70@gmail.com
 username419@gmail.com
 username744@gmail.com
```

how to save these out put  like *a = username394@gmail.co*  , 
 *b=username429@gmail.com* .....

Comment: Where do you want to save it? In a file, an array, DB etc?

Comment: store it where? a DB? a txt file..?

Comment: @ScaryWombat How is it duplicate of that question?

Comment: Please allow me to silently creep back into my hole

Comment: a DB and how to call it back?

Comment: Basically you need to get familiar with DB concepts and SQL probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need additional driver library for the database in which you are going to save these emails.

You can find jdbc driver for your database in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/).

For mysql database general code can look like:

```
ArrayList<String> objectsToStore = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        objectsToStore.add("username" + rnd.nextInt() + "@gmail.com");
    }

    try {
        //1) this used to load mysql jdbc driver into memory
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //2) create connection to running mysql instance
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?useSSL=false", "username", "password");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        for (String x : objectsToStore) {
            // this insert will work assuming you have table user_data with email field
            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USER_DATA (email) VALUES ('" + x +"')");
        }
        //commit transaction
        connection.commit();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

SQL for creating a table in database:

```
create table User_data(
  email varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Duplicate local variable objectsToStore

 at new_test.main(new_test.java:29)_

Comment: '(String objectsToStore: objectsToStore )' this line error

Comment: you duplicate variable name in a cycle. Should be '(String objectToStore : objectsToStore)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save them...thn declare a string[ ]  arrsy in outside of the loop....then try to store the mail addresses inside the string using nested loop...

And you can also store them in a text file using FileIlnputStrem class....ina txt file...

Comment: I told this answer to store them in a variable and txt file...not for DB

Comment: But OP says `a DB`